# How to implement chat gateway in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, nestjs, gateway

I have imported all the necessary imports for web-sockets for my app which uses TCP communication. I want to delete chat from both side like in whatsapp, read messages etc i.e. all the basic functionality in a chat module for any application, all the desired repository were injected which are not mention in code.
Code is running using npm run start:dev without any error.

I test above code with Chat controller through postman and it successfully saving desired data in database but when using real time in application then event is not fired.

Here what I trying to do is:

1. Send messages to a user but **socket event is not responding**.
2. **Also I want to  save chat in database.**

**Explanation:** I want to implement working chat  module api's for an application similar to whats-app chat.
for that I want to request user information that is to be save in the database
now I have created my functions for the same in a chat service file and also,  created events in the chat gateway file but ** the problem is I am not able to connect with the front-end**, when an event is fired from the front-end it does not behave as expected i.e. event does not point to my function at all resulting in no data entry in the database.

**EDIT:1** I've made some changes and now its working as expected. Later I'll post the changes.

Here is my code:

`import { SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway,OnGatewayInit, WsResponse, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect,  WebSocketServer} from '@nestjs/websockets';`

````
import { Logger, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Socket, Server } from 'socket.io';
import { ChatService }  from './chat.service';
import {CreateChatDto} from './dto';
import { Chats } from './entities/chat.entity';
import { ChatTos } from './entities/chat-to.entity';
import { Users } from '../user/entities/user.entity';
import { Repository, getRepository,Between, DeleteResult, UpdateResult, getConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { Events } from '../event/entities/event.entity';
import { Teams } from '../team/entities/team.entity';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';```

**Below  code is for websocket chat.**
    ```@WebSocketServer() wss: Server;
    private logger: Logger = new Logger('ChatGateway');
     wsClients=[];
     afterInit(server: Server) {
     console.log('Initialized!')
     this.logger.log('Initialized!');
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {

        console.log("disconnected")
        this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
      }



    handleConnection(client: any) {
        this.wsClients.push(client);
      }

  @SubscribeMessage('msgToServer')


    async handleMessage(@Req() request, client:Socket,dto: CreateChatDto) {

         // const {id,message,to_id,message_type,event_id,team_id } = dto;**commented code**
            const jwtData = await this.userService.jwtData(request.headers.authorization);
            const logged_id = jwtData.id; 
            this.chatService.sendMessage(logged_id, dto);
            console.log("savedChat")
            client.send('msgToServer', dto);
            return ({message:"Message sent"});
        } 

    @SubscribeMessage('readMessage')
    async readMessage(@Req() request, client:Socket,dto: CreateChatDto) {

    // const {id,message,to_id,message_type,event_id,team_id } = dto;
       const jwtData = await this.userService.jwtData(request.headers.authorization);
       const logged_id = jwtData.id; 
       this.chatService.readMessage(logged_id, dto);
       console.log("readChat")
       client.emit('readMessage', dto);
      return ({message:"Message read"});
    } 

    @SubscribeMessage('deleteMessage')
    async deleteMessage(@Req() request, client:Socket,dto: CreateChatDto) {

    // const {id,message,to_id,message_type,event_id,team_id } = dto;
       const jwtData = await this.userService.jwtData(request.headers.authorization);
       const logged_id = jwtData.id; 
       this.chatService.deleteMessage(logged_id, dto);
       console.log(" delete Chat")
       client.emit('deleteMessage', dto);
      return ({message:"Message deleted"});
    } 

}```
````

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MU Please see Explanation (newly edited).

Comment: I need you client code to see what's wrong. Any chance for minimal repo?

Comment: I'll share with you on any private service like on discord on Nestjs server, email etc